# Best way to package docker compose application as a service

Tags: package, puppet, docker-compose

I made a simple service using docker-compose that consist of 3 containers.  I'd like to package it up as a service so it is easier to control its lifecycle on a host.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Think about `Rancher`, a docker container manage tool, and easy to start up with it.

It supports docker-compose templates (rancher compose) and suitable for your request.

Furthermore, you can make it as rancher catalog. Rancher provides a catalog of application templates that make it easy to deploy these complex docker stacks.

You can refer the documents as start:

[Rancher quick start guide](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/latest/en/quick-start-guide/)

[Rancher catalog](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/latest/en/catalog/)

[Rancher compose](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.0/zh/rancher-compose/)

Comment: Thanks looks interesting.  Although right now I am looking for something very lightweight just to package up the existing app for the single host.